# Django celery not finding celery module

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to set up celery with Django from the tuts but I keep getting

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery'
```

I have a main project called Tasklist with the structure:

```
- Tasklist/
  - manage.py
  - Tasklist/
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
    - celery.py
    - urls.py
```

My **init**.py is as follows:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

And my celery.py is like so:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('')

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

I'm not sure if I need to alter the settings.py - but I'm running in a local environment so I shouldn't need to start a celery worker? I'm pretty confused!

I read that django-celery is redundant now the latest version of celery is here, so I only have celery 4.1.1 installed.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? Python can't find celery. Either it's not installed or you must make sure your celery worker can find the module.

Comment: ah yes I am! I have celery installed in the top level of my project but I will uninstall and install in the top level of my venv

Comment: Here's an article about this exception. It's hard or impossible for us to give a specific answer, because there's lots of ways to install python modules and set up the environment: http://www.daveoncode.com/2017/03/07/how-to-solve-python-modulenotfound-no-module-named-import-error/

Comment: That did solve it tho - I just made sure it was in the correct part of my venv

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. If celery installed on virtualEnv , Activate VirtualEnv
2. Navigate to path : `/path/to/Tasklist/` (to app name level)
3. Run `celery -A Tasklist worker -l info`

-A for App Name.

Celery Setup and Installation : [Official Document](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html)

In Settings.py Below setting can be managed.

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```