# Django not creating instance of Celery app

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm trying to automate some Django views using Celery but cannot get the Celery workers to start due to Django not importing the Celery instance. This a very similar problem to the post here:

[Django celery not finding celery module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785095/django-celery-not-finding-celery-module)

Note that I am not using a virtenv and I am on macos. All packages were installed at the root directory level (the folder for the project that I use for GitHub).

I named the project `iHand` and the application `app` from the Django setup instructions.

`app` has been added into the `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` to register the app:

```
# Application definitions
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app', # Created app
]
```

Instance of the `app` was created in `celery.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from django.conf import settings
from celery import Celery
import os

# Create a whole instance of the Django project
inst = Celery('app')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'iHand.settings')
inst.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
inst.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Created a package in the `__init__.py` located in `iHand/iHand/` dir:

```
# Load app when Django starts
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import inst as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

Created a `tasks.py` file in `iHand/app`:

```
# Import views and create tasks out of them
from celery import task
from app.views import (repositories, contributor,
                    teams, team_members, discussions)

# Get all of the repository names.
@task
repositories()
print('repositories executed')

# Get the contributors for each repository.
@task
contributor()
print('contributors executed')

# Get all of the teams in the organization.
@task
teams()
print('teams executed')

# Get all of the team members in each team.
@task
team_members()
print('team members executed')

# Get all discussions in each team.
@task
discussions()
print('discussions executed')
```

I've tried uninstalling Celery and reinstalling it from different levels of the project directory, creating a package in the same dir as the `tasks.py` but that didn't fix the issue either.

Here is the failure output:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

And the file structure:

```
iHand
├── app

│ ├── admin.py

│ ├── apps.py

│ ├── migrations

│ ├── models.py

│ ├── tasks.py

│ ├── templates

│ │ └── app

│ │ ├── discussions.html

│ │ ├── repositories.html

│ │ ├── repository.html

│ │ ├── team_members.html

│ │ └── teams.html

│ ├── tests.py

│ ├── urls.py

│ └── views.py

├── iHand

│ ├── __init__.py

│ ├── celery.py

│ ├── settings.py

│ ├── urls.py

│ └── wsgi.py

└── manage.py
```

Comment: Maybe I need to create a package in the same directory as my `tasks.py` file and that's why it's not loading. I am really confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Upon reading this tutorial here: https://www.merixstudio.com/blog/django-celery-beat/ it looks like one of the problems could be that I don't have a package created in my `iHand/` nor `iHand/app` directory which is why it's can't find app module. I am really confused as to what I would need to put in those files though